# Generate list of titles and thumbnails of Wordpress page's children

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

I want to have a PHP script that automatically generates a list of the childrens pages with their title, permalink and featured image. Now, I've got the bulk of the script done but when I run it it prints out three times (the number of how many child pages there are) the current pages title, thumbnail and permalink. See script and example below:

**Main script**

```
$type = 'page'; // CHILD OR SUB-PAGE

$args = array(
  'parent' => $post->ID,
  'child_of' => $post->ID,
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'sort_order' => 'DESC',
  'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
);

$count = 1;
$pages = get_pages($args);
foreach ($pages as $page) { setup_postdata( $page ); 
?>

<?php if ($count % 2 == 0) { ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/templates/element', 'infopic' ); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/templates/element', 'infolink' ); ?>


<?php } else { ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/templates/element', 'infolink' ); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/templates/element', 'infopic' ); ?>

<?php } //END ELSE ?>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

And these are the two included files. Checking whether `$count` is even or not is to alternate the content layout either text - image or image - text for a prettier layout.

**Element - Info Link**

```
global $page;

<div class="col-sm-6 dim-pad">
   <div class="big-text">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><h5><?php echo get_the_title($page->ID); ?></h5></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Element - Info pic**

```
<?php global $page; ?>

<div class="col-sm-6 dim-pad">
   <div class="info-image">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

But instead of it printing out the three child pages More Info, More Info Two, More Info Three, it just prints out Info, Info, Info which is the parent page.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `setup_postdata()` incorrectly.

For `setup_postdata()` to work you must use the variable, `$post`.

Change this:

```
foreach ($pages as $page) { setup_postdata( $page );
```

To:

```
foreach ( $pages as $post ) { 
    setup_postdata( $post );
```

Then inside your template parts remove `global $page;` and don't pass in `$page->ID` to any of those functions.

Finally after the foreach loop add:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This will restore your global `$post` value back to the parent page.

Comment: Perfect answer thanks man. Of course because `$pages` already has the sufficient arguments passed into it so the `$page` variable is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this may be the issue:

"Note that the 'hierarchical' parameter must be set to 0 (false) -- which is not default -- or else no results will be returned for any page other than the top level pages with no parent (ID=0) and the default all pages (ID=-1)."

...when specifying 'parent', you must set 'hierarchical' => '0',

hope I could help.
A.L.